# Different Font Styles in a String in an Array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Let's say I have this:

```
self.dictionary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"blah",
                           @"blah",
                           @"blah (blah)",
                           @"blah",
                           @"blah",
                           nil];
```

In the third object, I want to have the first "blah" with a larger font-size and a black font-color.  However, I want the second "blah" with the parentheses to be of a smaller size and a grey color.  How would I go about doing this?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html).

You would simply concatenate all yours strings and for each substring, figure what attributes you want, than call `- setAttributes:range:`.

Answer (score 0):

NSString doesn't allow you to have specific style. If your string need to have style/attributes, you will have to use NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you store just `NSString` objects. NSString doesn't have any font attached to it. If you want to keep font information - you can take a look at `NSAttributedString` class - https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html

So your code would look like:

```
self.items = @[
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"bla" attributes: @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12.0],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]
}],
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"bla" attributes: @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor grayColor]
}]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
NSArray *yourArr= @[@"blah",
                       @"blah",
                       @"blah (blah)",
                       @"blah",
                       @"blah"];


    for (NSString *word in yourArr)
    {
        if ([word isEqualToString:@"blah (blah)"])
        {

            [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString  alloc]initWithString:[word componentsSeparatedByString:@" "][0] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]}]];
            [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@" "]];
            [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString  alloc]initWithString:[word componentsSeparatedByString:@" "][1] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor grayColor]}]];
        }
        else
        {
            [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:word]];
        }
        [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@",\n"]];

    }
    self.yourAttStr=yourAtt;
```

[image]